# Deploying smart-contract

Tags: plutus

I'm have really trouble finding material that teach how to deploy a contract. Does someone here has already successfully deployed a smart-contract to the cardano test/mainnet? I need to know the steps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can checkout my repository that has working code on the testnet.  It is well documented and I also have a video of running the plutus code on the testnet.

https://github.com/lley154/cardano-lottery

Cheers,

Lawrence

Answer (score 0):

Until the Vasil Hardfork plutus scripts are attached to every transaction that spends from that contract. An example of how that can be done via the `cardano-cli` can be seen [here](https://docs.cardano.org/plutus/Plutus-transactions)

Once, Vasil HF has gone through you can actually store your plutus script on-chain and jsut use a script reference instead of attaching it to every tx.